# Remotely executing a command in a new persistent session on Windows Pro 7

Tags: windows-7, remote

I would like to execute, in an automated way, a command on a remote Windows 7 machine. Ideally I do not want to stay connected, but create a persistent session which I can later manually log back into (e.g. with remote desktop). I have been trying with psexec but no dice -- it freezes with various errors, sometimes without a message.

Comment: What command, specifically? The exact behavior of the command and the way it's designed will heavily influence what options are available to you.

Comment: Specifically I want to open an R environment and launch a computation (R script). The environment is available both as a GUI or as a CMD prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't insist on creating the persistent session on the fly, you can manually create one by logging into your machine via `RDP` (remote desktop).

Step 1: Login to your computer using RDP to create the persistent session. When you close the RDP session, make sure you **Disconnect** and do not **Log Off**. Disconnect keeps your session running even when you aren't connected to it; Log Off terminates the session and all programs running within it.

Step 2: Run some kind of SSH server (e.g. OpenSSH) within your persistent session. OpenSSH is free and gets the job done. There are other non-free ones too.

Step 3: Use an `ssh-agent` and an SSH client (e.g. PuTTY) to script the command desired over SSH.

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually, this is exactly the way I am doing things now. However, I would like to automate this process, i.e. not have to log in manually.

Comment: I guess you could use the `rdesktop` tool if you're running Linux on your client; you can automatically pass it your username and password, and set the user login script to fire off the computation. If you're only willing to run Windows as a client, no idea.

Comment: This [link](http://codeoptimism.com/2010/10/08/SSH-on-Windows-7-the-full-awesome-implementation) has a very nice setup.